# Statistical Significance of precision WITHOUT negative labels

Tags: classification, statistics

Let there be $n$ data points (examples) to be classified into 2 classes - either positive or negative. Let's say we have a model that outputs the probability of an example being of the positive class. I want to decide on an appropriate threshold for the probability - an example will be predicted as positive if the corresponding probability is more than the threshold.

The constraint is that I only know that $k$ of those examples are positives. I have **no information** on any true negatives. So for example if there are total 1500 examples, I might only know that 50 of them are positive class, and that's it.

If I set a threshold $T$, then I can count the no. of true positive examples whose probability score exceeds $T$. This gives me probability on the sample $P(>T\ |\ pos)$ where "$>T$" is the event of an example's probabilty score exceeding $T$. Then

$$P(pos\ |\ >T)=\frac{P(>T\ |\ pos)P(pos)}{P(>T)}$$

Now I know $P(>T)$ - I can just count the no. of examples exceeding the threshold. Assuming I have an estimate for $P(pos)$ as well, there's still the problem that $P(>T\ |\ pos)$ has been estimated on the sample and I don't know how it affects the final estimate of $P(pos\ |\ >T)$.

**Doubt: Is there a way to calculate some measure of confidence for the final probability estimate that I calculate?**

Comment: When you say "I might only know that 50 of them are positive class", do you mean that you are given the label for 50 of them (and they're positive) and the rest are unlabeled? Or that all of them are unlabeled and you are only told "there are at least 50 positive examples within all examples"

Comment: @AKareem: Sorry for the delayed response. I meant that I'm given the label for 50 of them (they're positive) and the rest are unlabeled